# WooCommerce product page format issue

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Not sure why my page has changed, but the text content always was held to the right of the image and now it shows below. Why would this happen?

https://smudgestationery.com/product/smudge-geek-on-fleek-hard-top-pencil-case/?w3tc_note=flush_all

Can it be adjusted with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove

```css
float: none;
width: 100%;
```

from the div `.summary.entry-summary.column one-second`

That should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for swift response, based on being out of comfort zone, whats the code block or custom css I need to put in please?!

Comment: The correct values are getting overwritten. If you add !important to the overwritten values it should be okay, or remove `.woocommerce-page div.product div.summary` in that block for these settings.

Comment: thanks so much, so what should the overwritten values be? I can do this via custom css then,...

Comment: I've added an image to my original post. There you can see the it
The values should be `float: right; width: 40%`

Comment: Although when i goto mobile screens there seems to be another issue in that the content is to thin for product descp

Comment: It looks quite good for me in the mobile view. Or maybe i didn't understood your issue.

Comment: Seems that the mobile style is being over written by the change made and making the content in a thin strip https://pasteboard.co/IWQAh0t.png and not full width, guess I need a style out for mobile screen size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208737/discussion-between-archer-and-dano007).